# How to write a RegExp to match the Nth character

Tags: regex, regular-language

There is a strings as below:

`2016,07,20,19,20,25`

How can I transfer this strings to such as this format string:

`2016-07-20 19:20:25`

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution with array slice could be this

```
let parts = [];
let date = "2016,07,20,19,20,25"; 
let formatted = ((parts = date.split(",")).slice(0,3)).join("-") + ' ' + parts.slice(3).join(":")
```

You could also do it with `String#replace` and a function as the 2 argument;

```
let date = "2016,07,20,19,20,25"; 
date.replace(/,/g, (() => {
  let count = 0;
  return (match, position) => {
    count += 1;
    if(count == 3) return ' ';
    else if(count < 3) return '-';
    else return ':';        
  });
})())
```

**Note:** Both approaches assume that the format will always be the one provided
6 numbers seperated by commas

Comment: if only regular expression to match?!

Comment: @JackyKwan what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that if only allows regex pattern to match, how?

Comment: @JackyKwan im not sure what you are asking

Comment: in other words, how to regex to match N-th ',' charactar? For example, how to match the 3rd ','?Thank you!

Comment: @JackyKwan you can use this to replace/capture nth occurence `'1,2,3,4,5'.replace(/((?:[^,]*,){2}[^,]*),/, '$1$')` . here replaces the 3rd comma with a `$`